# Print full path of location

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to print some stuff to a file from a Rascal program. So I build a location from the working dir using something like |cwd:///myFile|.

However, I could not find the file, so I tried printing this path.
But all I get is the same as what I put into the location. Hence I still do not know what the actual path is that will be used.

So how do I obtain the actual path that a location for a file or folder points to?

Something like this:

```
loc fileLoc = |cwd:///myFile.txt|;
writeFile(fileLoc, veryInterestingDataThatIsTooLargeForConsole);
println(Your file is saved here:);
loc actualFileLoc = getActualFileLoc(fileLoc);
println(actualFileLoc);
```

Comment: Or could use a name that does mean something to you, like `home:///myFile.txt` for a file in your personal directory or `tmp:///myFile.txt` for a file in the temp folder of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `resolveLocation` function in the `IO` library:

```
rascal>loc fileLoc = |cwd:///myFile.txt|;
loc: |cwd:///myFile.txt|
rascal>import IO;
ok
rascal>resolveLocation(fileLoc);
loc: |file:///Users/mhills/Development/eclipse.versions/eclipse.45.rcp/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/myFile.txt|
```

Comment: Note that this will work for certain URI schemes, but not for all. For `project` for example you will just get the original location back. For `home` and `cwd` it works because these are defined in terms of the local file system.

Comment: Hi @JurgenVinju, can we use this to obtain full `readlink -f FILE` ([man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink)) functionality in Rascal? For example `resolveLocation(|cwd:///../|)` will still contain `../` in the resolved path.

Comment: Hi Teun. No `..` is not implemented -for security reasons- to go beyond the root of a filesystem.